# jQuery AJAX post data gets lost because of routing in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to pass an ID to a PHP script using ajax. it worked just fine when using the following:

```
var baseURL = '/W4W/public/';

function voteUp(){
    var snippetID = document.getElementById('snippetID').innerHTML;
voteThing('vote_up', snippetID);
}

function voteThing(URL, snippetID){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    data: {codesnip_id: snippetID},
    success: function(data) {
                    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "updateVotes",
            data: {codesnip_id: snippetID}
            success: function(data1) {}
        });
        }
    }); 
}
```

PHP routes and PHP script:

```
Route::post('codesnippet/{codesnip_id}/vote_up', array('uses' => 'VoteController@votedUp'));

public function votedDown($codesnip_id){
        // Some irrelevant code for this issue
}
```

but when I instead use the following routes:

```
Route::post('vote_down', array('uses' => 'VoteController@votedDown'));
```

and the following javascript:

```
function voteDown(){
    var snippet_ID = document.getElementById('snippetID').innerHTML;
    URLS = baseURL + 'vote_down';
    voteThing(URLS, snippet_ID);
```

the data never reaches the PHP script. I get the following error:
    }

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Missing argument 1 for VoteController::votedDown()","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\W4W\\app\\controllers\\VoteController.php","line":69}}
```

So I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the routing, causing the dataloss. However I'm out of ideas what it might be. couldn't find and specifics about it anywhere either

Comment: What is the value of URL?

Answer (score 0):

the data reaches your php script, because your php script is throwing an exception,

your vote_down function expects the argument $codesnip_id

```
votedDown($codesnip_id)
```

but in your route you are not passing any argument like you did for vote_up

so instead get the $codesnip_id from posted formdata, as the ajax is passing the data as POST-data and not as a part of the url

```
votedDown() {
   $codesnip_id=$_POST['codesnip_id'];
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your `votedDown` method

```
public function votedDown($codesnip_id){
    // Some irrelevant code for this issue
}
```

According to your error message you didn't pass the argument it requires, so pass the argument with the `url` as second parameter in the url using something like:

```
var snippet_ID = document.getElementById('snippetID').innerHTML;
URLS = baseURL + 'vote_down/' + snippet_ID;
voteThing(URLS);
```

In this case the route should be:

```
Route::post('vote_down/{id}', array('uses' => 'VoteController@votedDown'));
```

Alternatively, you may pass it to `POST` as you are passing now but remove the `$codesnip_id` from the method, so it could be:

```
public function votedDown(){
    $codesnip_id = Input::get('snippet_ID');
}
```

In this case, `snippet_ID` should be like `'snippet_ID=' + snippet_ID`.